# Assigning a label to its corresponding grid cell

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, multidimensional-array

I coded a YOLO model from scratch and have a numpy array which looks like this:

```
[
 [[1 0 1 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1]
 [1 1 0 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
 ...]
```

This is how it would look in a pandas object:

```
Obj_score c1 c2 x y h w 
1 0 1 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1
1 1 0 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

In order to make my model work I have to convert the mentioned label tensor into a `S*S*(B*5+C)` tensor, where I have to put each label into its corresponding grid cell. How would I do that?

The model of mine makes 3 bounding box predictions (which is called B), 2 class predictions (which is called C), and it S = 7.
How would I put my labels into its corresponding grid cell (by using numpy or keras)?

If it would help [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maskaravivek/d456a82ae08517fe0bb1964c22f56ced/raw/36e95091bca46d9b578b13f231637c28630705bb/4db7d8e6-bf84-4af8-a870-f6f18c02b465) some code from Vivek Maskara's solution to this issue which can also be found in his article about implementing YOLO v1 in scratch.

Comment: What is S, B and C? Could you provide an examples for us to play with?

Comment: @Rafael When using the YOLO algorithm the image is divided into S*S grid of cells.
Each grid predicts B bounding boxes.
C is how many classes the model predicts. Hope that helps

Comment: @RafaelValero the values are stated in the questions description

Comment: I think more code / data should help a lot when writing an answer to this. Unless someone writes this from scratch exactly the way you did, it'll take a lot of time to figure this out. Can you maybe post/link more of your (maybe simplified) code?

Comment: @JakubŽitný I can but it is barely related to my question (its just the data loading algorithm, some data preparation e.g reshaping of the images, and the model). The code I have written barely addresses this issue due to the fact that I have no clue where to even begin and my previous attempts came nowhere near to a solution.

Comment: @JakubŽitný Here is some code that I have found which might help with a solution (Its from Vivek Maskara's implementation of the YOLO v1 algorithm) as that is the way he tackled the issue:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maskaravivek/d456a82ae08517fe0bb1964c22f56ced/raw/36e95091bca46d9b578b13f231637c28630705bb/4db7d8e6-bf84-4af8-a870-f6f18c02b465

Comment: @jr123456jr987654321 And what are your problems with implementing said approach?

Comment: @J.M.Arnold If you mean why am I not using the code of Vivek Masakara, that is due to me being unable to convert his code into something that works for me. I would be glad if you would be able help me with that.