# Reformatting a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have come across some code (which may answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936033/assigning-a-label-to-its-corresponding-grid-cell) question of mine). Here is the code (from Vivek Maskara's solution to my issue):

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def read(image_path, label):
    image = cv.imread(image_path)
    image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image_h, image_w = image.shape[0:2]
    image = cv.resize(image, (448, 448))
    image = image / 255.

    label_matrix = np.zeros([7, 7, 30])
    for l in label:
        l = l.split(',')
        l = np.array(l, dtype=np.int)
        xmin = l[0]
        ymin = l[1]
        xmax = l[2]
        ymax = l[3]
        cls = l[4]
        x = (xmin + xmax) / 2 / image_w
        y = (ymin + ymax) / 2 / image_h
        w = (xmax - xmin) / image_w
        h = (ymax - ymin) / image_h
        loc = [7 * x, 7 * y]
        loc_i = int(loc[1])
        loc_j = int(loc[0])
        y = loc[1] - loc_i
        x = loc[0] - loc_j

        if label_matrix[loc_i, loc_j, 24] == 0:
            label_matrix[loc_i, loc_j, cls] = 1
            label_matrix[loc_i, loc_j, 20:24] = [x, y, w, h]
            label_matrix[loc_i, loc_j, 24] = 1  # response

    return image, label_matrix
```

Would it be possible for you to explain how this part of the code works and what it specifically does:

```
if label_matrix[loc_i, loc_j, 24] == 0:
    label_matrix[loc_i, loc_j, cls] = 1
    label_matrix[loc_i, loc_j, 20:24] = [x, y, w, h]
    label_matrix[loc_i, loc_j, 24] = 1  # response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will first create and explain a simplified example, and then explain the part you pointed.

First, we create the ndarray named `label_matrix`:

```
import numpy as np
label_matrix = np.ones([2, 3, 4])
print(label_matrix)
```

This code means that you wil get an array containing 2 arrays, each of these 2 arrays will contain 3 arrays, and each of these 3 arrays will contain 4 elements.
And because we used `np.ones`, all these elements will have a value of `1`.
So, printing `label_matrix` wil output this:

```
[[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]]
```

Now, we will change the values of first 4 elements of the first array contained by the first array of `label_matrix`.

To acces *the first array of `label_matrix`*, we do: `label_matrix[0]`

To access *the first array contained by the first array of `label_matrix`* we do:  `label_matrix[0, 0]`

To access the first element of the first array contained by the first array of `label_matrix` we do: `label_matrix[0, 0, 0]`

To access the second element of the first array contained by the first array of `label_matrix` we do: `label_matrix[0, 0, 1]`

etc.

So, now, we will change the values of first 4 elements of the first array contained by the first array of `label_matrix`:

```
label_matrix[0, 0, 0] = 100
label_matrix[0, 0, 1] = 200
label_matrix[0, 0, 2] = 300
label_matrix[0, 0, 2] = 400
```

Output of `label_matrix`:

```
[[[100. 200. 300. 400.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.]]

 [[  1.   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.]]]
```

But we could have written it like this, instead of wrting 4 lines of codes:

```
label_matrix[0, 0, 0:4] = [100,200,300,400]
```

Writing `label_matrix[0, 0, 0:4]` means:
in the first array contained by the first array of `label_matrix`, select the 4 first elements (from index 0 to 4 (4 being not included))

So now you know the meaning of each line.

I'll explain the part of code you pointed:

`if label_matrix[loc_i, loc_j, 24] == 0:`:

Test if the element at index 24 (the 23th element) has value `0`

if yes, then:

`label_matrix[loc_i, loc_j, cls] = 1`:

assign the value `1` to the element at index `cls`. (If the variable named `cls` has value `4`, it will assigne the value `1` to the element at index 4 of the first array contained by the first array of `label_matrix`)

`label_matrix[loc_i, loc_j, 20:24] = [x, y, w, h]`:

Say "x==100", "y==200", "w==300" and "h==400". So, in the first array contained by the first array of `label_matrix`, assign value `100` to the elemnt at index `20`, value `200` to the elemnt at index `21`, `300` at index `22` and `400` to index `23`

`label_matrix[loc_i, loc_j, 24] = 1`:

in the first array contained by the first array of `label_matrix`, assign value `1` to the element at index `24`